# Add a second Exchange 2010 server to enable upgrade to SP3

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, directed-acyclic-graphs

One of our customers has 1 (Virtual) Windows server 2008r2 enterprice server which is a root DC with Exchange 2010 sp1. 
They want to upgrade Exchange to SP3 so they can easily migrate to Office 365.

Since there is no proper backup and according to Microsoft there is no way to rollback after installing SP3, I'm not comfortable to just go ahead and upgrade.

The idea is now to install a second Exchange 2010 server but one with SP3, migrate or sync the mail database to temporary have a redundant setup. Then when all is synced, the 'old' server can be upgraded to SP3 as well, and the new server can be taken offline.

Is this the right approach?

Regards,

Comment: imho, this is a Server Fault question. voted to move there.

Comment: @Jayan thank you, will move it!